# Design Shopping Cart System Interview Problem [Python 3]

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented, interview-questions, e-commerce

Just practicing some objected oriented design questions. Please let me know what can be improved to be more OOD and extensible. Thank you.

Functional Requirements

- Cart can hold multiple products
- A product has a name and price. Name is unique.
- Should show the total price
- Should show itemized price
- Should be able to add/remove products

Follow up

- Checkout
- Inventory
- Add/remove/apply promotions

Misc

```
def floor_to_nearest_two(number):
    return int(number * 100) / 100


class NotEnoughCartItem(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('Not enough items in the cart')


class NotEnoughInventoryItem(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('Not enough items in the inventory')


class InvalidInput(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg):
        super().__init__(msg)
```

Product

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self, product_id, name, price):
        self.product_id = product_id
        self.name = name
        self.price = price

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Product: {self.name}, Price: ${self.price}'
```

InventoryItem

```
class InventoryItem:
    def __init__(self, product):
        self.product = product
        self.count = 0

    def update_item_count(self, count):
        if count == 0:
            return
        if count < 0 and self.count < count:
            raise NotEnoughInventoryItem()

        self.count += count

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.product}, Count: {self.count}'
```

CartItem

```
class CartItem:
    def __init__(self, product):
        self.product = product
        self.count = 0
        self.total_price = 0

    def update_item_count(self, count):
        self.count += count

        price_delta = self.product.price * count
        self.total_price += price_delta

        return price_delta

    # If the price of a product gets changed after the product is added to the cart,
    #   the cart should reflect it.
    def recalculate_total_price(self):
        self.total_price = self.product.price * self.count

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Product: {self.product.name}, Count: {self.count}, ' \
               f'Total: ${floor_to_nearest_two(number=self.total_price)}'
```

Cart

```
class Cart:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items: dict[int, CartItem] = dict()
        self.total_price = 0

    def add_item(self, product, count=1):
        if count <= 0:
            raise InvalidInput('Count must be a positive integer.')

        item = self.items.setdefault(product.product_id, CartItem(product))
        price_delta = item.update_item_count(count=count)
        self.total_price += price_delta

    def remove_item(self, product, count=1):
        if count <= 0:
            raise InvalidInput('Count must be a positive integer.')

        item = self.items.get(product.product_id, None)
        if not item or item.count < count:
            raise NotEnoughCartItem()

        price_delta = item.update_item_count(count=-count)
        self.total_price += price_delta

        if item.count == 0:
            del self.items[product.product_id]

    def delete_item(self, product):
        item = self.items.get(product.product_id, None)
        if not item:
            return

        self.remove_item(product=product, count=item.count)

    def empty_cart(self):
        self.items.clear()
        self.total_price = 0

    def recalculate_total_prices(self):
        self.total_price = 0
        for item in self.items.values():
            item.recalculate_total_price()
            self.total_price += item.total_price

    def __str__(self):
        result = 'Cart\n'
        for item in self.items.values():
            result += f'{str(item)}\n'

        result += f'Total Price: ${floor_to_nearest_two(number=self.total_price)}'
        return result
```

Inventory

```
class Inventory:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items: dict[int, InventoryItem] = dict()

    def add_item(self, product, count=1):
        if count <= 0:
            raise InvalidInput('Count must be a positive integer.')

        item = self.items.setdefault(product.product_id, InventoryItem(product))
        item.update_item_count(count=count)

    def remove_item(self, product, count=1):
        if count <= 0:
            raise InvalidInput('Count must be a positive integer.')

        item = self.items.get(product.product_id, None)
        if not item or item.count < count:
            raise NotEnoughInventoryItem()

        item.update_item_count(count=-count)

    def check_stock(self, product, count):
        item = self.items.get(product.product_id, None)
        if not item or item.count < count:
            return False

        return True

    def __str__(self):
        result = 'Inventory\n'
        for item in self.items.values():
            result += f'{item}\n'

        return result
```

Promotions

```
class BasePromotion:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def apply_promotion(self, count, product_price):
        raise NotImplementedError()


class DiscountPromotion(BasePromotion):

    def __init__(self, name, discount_percentage):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.multiplier = 1 - discount_percentage / 100

    def apply_promotion(self, count, product_price):
        return count * product_price * self.multiplier


class BuyOneGetXPromotion(BasePromotion):
    def __init__(self, name, x):
        if x <= 0:
            raise InvalidInput('x must be a positive integer')
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.x = x

    def apply_promotion(self, count, product_price):
        divider = self.x + 1
        return (count // divider + (0 if count % divider == 0 else 1)) * product_price
```

ReceiptItem

```
class ReceiptItem:
    def __init__(self, product_name, price, count, original_total, final_total):
        self.product_name = product_name
        self.price = price
        self.count = count
        self.original_total = original_total
        self.final_total = final_total

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.product_name}: ${self.price} * {self.count}.' \
               f' Original: ${floor_to_nearest_two(number=self.original_total)}' \
               f' => Final: ${floor_to_nearest_two(number=self.final_total)}'
```

Receipt

```
class Receipt:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items: list[ReceiptItem] = list()
        self.original_total = 0
        self.final_total = 0

    def add_item(self, item: ReceiptItem):
        self.items.append(item)

    def __str__(self):
        result = 'Receipt\n'
        for item in self.items:
            result += f'{str(item)}\n'

        result += f'Original Total: ${floor_to_nearest_two(number=self.original_total)}\n'
        result += f'Final Total: ${floor_to_nearest_two(number=self.final_total)}\n'
        return result
```

CheckoutManager

```
class CheckoutManager:
    def __init__(self, inventory: Inventory):
        self.inventory = inventory
        self.promotions: dict[int, BasePromotion] = dict()

    def add_promo(self, product_id, promo: BasePromotion):
        # Product does not need to exist in the inventory since the user may add the promo first.
        # Latest promo overrides any existing ones.
        self.promotions[product_id] = promo

    def remove_promo(self, product_id):
        if product_id not in self.promotions:
            return

        del self.promotions[product_id]

    def checkout(self, cart: Cart):
        if not cart.items:
            raise NotEnoughCartItem()

        for cart_item in cart.items.values():
            inventory_item = self.inventory.items.get(cart_item.product.product_id, None)
            if not inventory_item or inventory_item.count < cart_item.count:
                raise NotEnoughInventoryItem()

        receipt = Receipt()
        original_total_price = 0
        final_total_price = 0
        for cart_item in cart.items.values():
            product = cart_item.product
            self.inventory.remove_item(product=product, count=cart_item.count)

            total_price = cart_item.total_price
            original_total_price += total_price

            receipt_item = ReceiptItem(
                product_name=product.name, price=product.price, count=cart_item.count,
                original_total=total_price, final_total=total_price)
            receipt.add_item(item=receipt_item)

            promo = self.promotions.get(product.product_id, None)
            if promo:
                total_price = promo.apply_promotion(count=cart_item.count, product_price=product.price)
                receipt_item.final_total = total_price

            final_total_price += total_price

        receipt.original_total = original_total_price
        receipt.final_total = final_total_price

        cart.empty_cart()
        print(f'Checkout Successful!\n{receipt}')
```

Test Code

```
def test():
    fuji_apple = Product(product_id=1, name='Fuji Apple', price=2.5)
    gala_apple = Product(product_id=2, name='Gala Apple', price=3)
    milk = Product(product_id=3, name='Milk', price=4.99)
    coke = Product(product_id=4, name='Coke', price=2)

    inventory = Inventory()
    inventory.add_item(product=fuji_apple, count=10)
    inventory.add_item(product=gala_apple, count=100)
    inventory.add_item(product=milk, count=50)
    inventory.add_item(product=coke)
    inventory.add_item(product=coke)
    inventory.add_item(product=coke)
    print(f'{inventory}\n')

    fuji_discount_promo = DiscountPromotion(name='Fuji 30% Discount!', discount_percentage=30)
    gala_discount_promo = DiscountPromotion(name='Gala 50% Discount!', discount_percentage=50)
    milk_buy_one_get_3_promo = BuyOneGetXPromotion(name='Buy One Milk and Get Three!', x=3)

    checkout_manager = CheckoutManager(inventory=inventory)
    checkout_manager.add_promo(product_id=fuji_apple.product_id, promo=fuji_discount_promo)
    checkout_manager.add_promo(product_id=gala_apple.product_id, promo=gala_discount_promo)
    checkout_manager.add_promo(product_id=milk.product_id, promo=milk_buy_one_get_3_promo)

    cart = Cart()
    cart.add_item(product=fuji_apple)
    cart.add_item(product=fuji_apple, count=3)
    cart.add_item(product=gala_apple, count=5)
    cart.add_item(product=milk, count=10)
    cart.add_item(product=coke)
    cart.add_item(product=coke)
    cart.add_item(product=coke)
    print(f'{cart}\n')

    cart.remove_item(product=coke)
    print(f'{cart}\n')

    cart.remove_item(product=coke, count=2)
    print(f'{cart}\n')

    gala_apple.price = 1
    print(f'{cart}\n')
    cart.recalculate_total_prices()
    print(f'{cart}\n')

    cart.delete_item(product=milk)
    print(f'{cart}\n')

    cart.add_item(product=milk, count=9)
    checkout_manager.checkout(cart=cart)
    print(f'{cart}\n')
    print(f'{inventory}\n')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Broadly speaking this does a lot of things right: self-written exceptions, (the start of) type hinting, overridden `__str__`, etc.

`floor_to_nearest_two` is dubious. There are better ways to round down - floor-division `//` probably suiting you - but you should you be rounding at all? And if you do, can you wait until the output stage? If you can wait (which is ideal), just use `.2f` in a format string or better yet call `currency()` which includes rounding and a currency symbol.

You need more type hints. You need to hint every method parameter and return value; if there's no return mark it `-> None`.

You can delete the `__init__` from `InvalidInput` and assume the constructor of the parent; just write `pass`.

`if count < 0 and self.count < count` is odd. I guess you're passing a negative `count` if you're removing from inventory; but in a case like that, shouldn't it be

`if count + self.count < 0`

?

Your mutation model is problematic, and with it the `update` and `recalculate` methods. It's understandable for some of your classes to need to mutate, e.g. `Cart`; but at this scale re-calculating price subtotals and totals is so cheap that you should just have a one-pass total calculation function, no persisted totals or subtotals, and no price updating. Currently the recalculation strategy is fragile, vulnerable to bugs (even if there aren't any currently).

Prefer paren-wrapping `()` instead of escaping `\` for multi-line string expressions.

`dict()` and `list()` are equivalent to literals `{}` and `[]`.

Rather than loops like this:

```
    for item in self.items.values():
        result += f'{str(item)}\n'
```

prefer `'\n'.join()`.

This:

```
def apply_promotion(self, count, product_price):
    divider = self.x + 1
    return (count // divider + (0 if count % divider == 0 else 1)) * product_price
```

is a little nasty. If I understand correctly, a more legible way of expressing this "buy one get X" is

```
divider = self.x + 1       # e.g. buy one get 3 -> divider = 4
groups = count // divider  # number of item groups
if count % divider:        # if purchase count is not an even multiple
    groups += 1            # pay for the last group
return groups + product_price  # pay once per group
```

Rather than `remove_promo` early-returning, invert the condition.

`.get(x, None)` is just `.get(x)`.

You should convert your test method to actual tests - don't `print`; add `assert`s.

### Suggested

Covering some of the above,

```
from locale import currency, LC_ALL, setlocale

setlocale(LC_ALL, '')


class NotEnoughCartItem(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('Not enough items in the cart')


class NotEnoughInventoryItem(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('Not enough items in the inventory')


class InvalidInput(Exception):
    pass


class Product:
    def __init__(self, product_id: int, name: str, price: float) -> None:
        self.product_id = product_id
        self.name = name
        self.price = price

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'Product: {self.name}, Price: {currency(self.price)}'


class InventoryItem:
    def __init__(self, product: Product) -> None:
        self.product = product
        self.count = 0

    def update_item_count(self, count: int) -> None:
        if count == 0:
            return
        if count < 0 and self.count < count:
            raise NotEnoughInventoryItem()

        self.count += count

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.product}, Count: {self.count}'


class CartItem:
    def __init__(self, product: Product) -> None:
        self.product = product
        self.count = 0
        self.total_price = 0

    def update_item_count(self, count: int) -> float:
        self.count += count

        price_delta = self.product.price * count
        self.total_price += price_delta

        return price_delta

    def recalculate_total_price(self) -> None:
        """
        If the price of a product gets changed after the product is added to the cart,
        the cart should reflect it.
        """
        self.total_price = self.product.price * self.count

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return (
            f'Product: {self.product.name}, Count: {self.count}, '
            f'Total: {currency(self.total_price)}'
        )


class Cart:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.items: dict[int, CartItem] = {}
        self.total_price = 0

    def add_item(self, product: Product, count: int = 1) -> None:
        if count <= 0:
            raise InvalidInput('Count must be a positive integer.')

        item = self.items.setdefault(product.product_id, CartItem(product))
        price_delta = item.update_item_count(count=count)
        self.total_price += price_delta

    def remove_item(self, product: Product, count: int = 1) -> None:
        if count <= 0:
            raise InvalidInput('Count must be a positive integer.')

        item = self.items.get(product.product_id)
        if not item or item.count < count:
            raise NotEnoughCartItem()

        price_delta = item.update_item_count(count=-count)
        self.total_price += price_delta

        if item.count == 0:
            del self.items[product.product_id]

    def delete_item(self, product: Product) -> None:
        item = self.items.get(product.product_id, None)
        if item:
            self.remove_item(product=product, count=item.count)

    def empty_cart(self):
        self.items.clear()
        self.total_price = 0

    def recalculate_total_prices(self) -> None:
        self.total_price = 0
        for item in self.items.values():
            item.recalculate_total_price()
            self.total_price += item.total_price

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        result = (
            'Cart\n'
            + '\n'.join(str(item) for item in self.items.values())
            + f'Total Price: {currency(self.total_price)}'
        )
        return result


class Inventory:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.items: dict[int, InventoryItem] = dict()

    def add_item(self, product: Product, count: int = 1) -> None:
        if count <= 0:
            raise InvalidInput('Count must be a positive integer.')

        item = self.items.setdefault(product.product_id, InventoryItem(product))
        item.update_item_count(count=count)

    def remove_item(self, product: Product, count: int = 1) -> None:
        if count <= 0:
            raise InvalidInput('Count must be a positive integer.')

        item = self.items.get(product.product_id)
        if not item or item.count < count:
            raise NotEnoughInventoryItem()

        item.update_item_count(count=-count)

    def check_stock(self, product: Product, count: int) -> bool:
        item = self.items.get(product.product_id, None)
        if not item or item.count < count:
            return False

        return True

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        result = 'Inventory\n' + '\n'.join(str(v) for v in self.items.values())
        return result


class BasePromotion:
    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name

    def apply_promotion(self, count: int, product_price: float) -> float:
        raise NotImplementedError()


class DiscountPromotion(BasePromotion):

    def __init__(self, name: str, discount_percentage: float) -> None:
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.multiplier = 1 - discount_percentage / 100

    def apply_promotion(self, count: int, product_price: float) -> float:
        return count * product_price * self.multiplier


class BuyOneGetXPromotion(BasePromotion):
    def __init__(self, name: str, x: int) -> None:
        if x <= 0:
            raise InvalidInput('x must be a positive integer')
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.x = x

    def apply_promotion(self, count: int, product_price: float) -> float:
        divider = self.x + 1
        return (count // divider + (0 if count % divider == 0 else 1)) * product_price


class ReceiptItem:
    def __init__(
        self,
        product_name: str,
        price: float,
        count: int,
        original_total: float,
        final_total: float,
    ) -> None:
        self.product_name = product_name
        self.price = price
        self.count = count
        self.original_total = original_total
        self.final_total = final_total

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return (
            f'{self.product_name}: {currency(self.price)} * {self.count}.'
            f' Original: {currency(self.original_total)}'
            f' => Final: {currency(self.final_total)}'
        )


class Receipt:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.items: list[ReceiptItem] = []
        self.original_total = 0
        self.final_total = 0

    def add_item(self, item: ReceiptItem):
        self.items.append(item)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        result = (
            'Receipt\n'
            + '\n'.join(str(item) for item in self.items)
            + f'Original Total: {currency(self.original_total)}\n'
            + f'Final Total: {currency(self.final_total)}\n'
        )
        return result


class CheckoutManager:
    def __init__(self, inventory: Inventory) -> None:
        self.inventory = inventory
        self.promotions: dict[int, BasePromotion] = dict()

    def add_promo(self, product_id: int, promo: BasePromotion) -> None:
        # Product does not need to exist in the inventory since the user may add the promo first.
        # Latest promo overrides any existing ones.
        self.promotions[product_id] = promo

    def remove_promo(self, product_id: int) -> None:
        if product_id not in self.promotions:
            return

        del self.promotions[product_id]

    def checkout(self, cart: Cart) -> None:
        if not cart.items:
            raise NotEnoughCartItem()

        for cart_item in cart.items.values():
            inventory_item = self.inventory.items.get(cart_item.product.product_id)
            if not inventory_item or inventory_item.count < cart_item.count:
                raise NotEnoughInventoryItem()

        receipt = Receipt()
        original_total_price = 0
        final_total_price = 0
        for cart_item in cart.items.values():
            product = cart_item.product
            self.inventory.remove_item(product=product, count=cart_item.count)

            total_price = cart_item.total_price
            original_total_price += total_price

            receipt_item = ReceiptItem(
                product_name=product.name, price=product.price, count=cart_item.count,
                original_total=total_price, final_total=total_price)
            receipt.add_item(item=receipt_item)

            promo = self.promotions.get(product.product_id, None)
            if promo:
                total_price = promo.apply_promotion(count=cart_item.count, product_price=product.price)
                receipt_item.final_total = total_price

            final_total_price += total_price

        receipt.original_total = original_total_price
        receipt.final_total = final_total_price

        cart.empty_cart()
        print(f'Checkout Successful!\n{receipt}')


def test() -> None:
    fuji_apple = Product(product_id=1, name='Fuji Apple', price=2.5)
    gala_apple = Product(product_id=2, name='Gala Apple', price=3)
    milk = Product(product_id=3, name='Milk', price=4.99)
    coke = Product(product_id=4, name='Coke', price=2)

    inventory = Inventory()
    inventory.add_item(product=fuji_apple, count=10)
    inventory.add_item(product=gala_apple, count=100)
    inventory.add_item(product=milk, count=50)
    inventory.add_item(product=coke)
    inventory.add_item(product=coke)
    inventory.add_item(product=coke)
    print(f'{inventory}\n')

    fuji_discount_promo = DiscountPromotion(name='Fuji 30% Discount!', discount_percentage=30)
    gala_discount_promo = DiscountPromotion(name='Gala 50% Discount!', discount_percentage=50)
    milk_buy_one_get_3_promo = BuyOneGetXPromotion(name='Buy One Milk and Get Three!', x=3)

    checkout_manager = CheckoutManager(inventory=inventory)
    checkout_manager.add_promo(product_id=fuji_apple.product_id, promo=fuji_discount_promo)
    checkout_manager.add_promo(product_id=gala_apple.product_id, promo=gala_discount_promo)
    checkout_manager.add_promo(product_id=milk.product_id, promo=milk_buy_one_get_3_promo)

    cart = Cart()
    cart.add_item(product=fuji_apple)
    cart.add_item(product=fuji_apple, count=3)
    cart.add_item(product=gala_apple, count=5)
    cart.add_item(product=milk, count=10)
    cart.add_item(product=coke)
    cart.add_item(product=coke)
    cart.add_item(product=coke)
    print(f'{cart}\n')

    cart.remove_item(product=coke)
    print(f'{cart}\n')

    cart.remove_item(product=coke, count=2)
    print(f'{cart}\n')

    gala_apple.price = 1
    print(f'{cart}\n')
    cart.recalculate_total_prices()
    print(f'{cart}\n')

    cart.delete_item(product=milk)
    print(f'{cart}\n')

    cart.add_item(product=milk, count=9)
    checkout_manager.checkout(cart=cart)
    print(f'{cart}\n')
    print(f'{inventory}\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

### Output

```
Inventory
Product: Fuji Apple, Price: $2.50, Count: 10
Product: Gala Apple, Price: $3.00, Count: 100
Product: Milk, Price: $4.99, Count: 50
Product: Coke, Price: $2.00, Count: 3

Cart
Product: Fuji Apple, Count: 4, Total: $10.00
Product: Gala Apple, Count: 5, Total: $15.00
Product: Milk, Count: 10, Total: $49.90
Product: Coke, Count: 3, Total: $6.00Total Price: $80.90

Cart
Product: Fuji Apple, Count: 4, Total: $10.00
Product: Gala Apple, Count: 5, Total: $15.00
Product: Milk, Count: 10, Total: $49.90
Product: Coke, Count: 2, Total: $4.00Total Price: $78.90

Cart
Product: Fuji Apple, Count: 4, Total: $10.00
Product: Gala Apple, Count: 5, Total: $15.00
Product: Milk, Count: 10, Total: $49.90Total Price: $74.90

Cart
Product: Fuji Apple, Count: 4, Total: $10.00
Product: Gala Apple, Count: 5, Total: $15.00
Product: Milk, Count: 10, Total: $49.90Total Price: $74.90

Cart
Product: Fuji Apple, Count: 4, Total: $10.00
Product: Gala Apple, Count: 5, Total: $5.00
Product: Milk, Count: 10, Total: $49.90Total Price: $64.90

Cart
Product: Fuji Apple, Count: 4, Total: $10.00
Product: Gala Apple, Count: 5, Total: $5.00Total Price: $15.00

Checkout Successful!
Receipt
Fuji Apple: $2.50 * 4. Original: $10.00 => Final: $7.00
Gala Apple: $1.00 * 5. Original: $5.00 => Final: $2.50
Milk: $4.99 * 9. Original: $44.91 => Final: $14.97Original Total: $59.91
Final Total: $24.47

Cart
Total Price: $0.00

Inventory
Product: Fuji Apple, Price: $2.50, Count: 6
Product: Gala Apple, Price: $1.00, Count: 95
Product: Milk, Price: $4.99, Count: 41
Product: Coke, Price: $2.00, Count: 3
```

Comment: Awesome! These feedbacks are really helpful. I really appreciate it. Thank you very much!