# Small shopping cart application - Solid Principles and Clean Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented, interview-questions

I've recently had a technical interview where I had to identify code smells and refactor an existing code by applying the SOLID principles and implementing unit tests.

It is a small shopping cart application with a small set of eCommerce/shopping cart rules. Rules include calculation of total price, discount and loyalty points calculation.

Existing Business Rules:

- Calculates total price and total loyalty points earned by the customer.
- Products with product code starting with DIS_10 have a 10% discount applied.
- Products with product code starting with DIS_15 have a 15% discount applied.
- Loyalty points are earned more when the product is not under any offer.

  - Customer earns 1 point on every $5 purchase.
  - Customer earns 1 point on every $10 spent on a product with 10% discount.
  - Customer earns 1 point on every $15 spent on a product with 15% discount.

Most of the business logic was implemented in single method `ShoppingCart.checkout`.

Here's the whole application before refactoring:

Models:

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self, price, product_code, name):
        self.price = price
        self.product_code = product_code
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return " Name: %s \n Price: %s \n" % (self.name, self.price)

class Customer:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class Order:
    def __init__(self, loyalty_points_earned=0, total_price=0):
        self.loyalty_points = loyalty_points_earned
        self.total = total_price

    def __str__(self):
        return "Total price: %s \nWill receive %s" % (self.total, self.loyalty_points)
```

ShoppingCart:

```
class ShoppingCart:
    def __init__(self, customer=Customer, products=[]):
        self.products = products
        self.customer = customer

    def add_product(self, product):
        self.products.append(product)

    def checkout(self):
        total_price = 0.00
        loyalty_points_earned = 0.00
        for product in self.products:
            discount = 0.00
            if product.product_code.startswith("DIS_10"):
                loyalty_points_earned += (product.price / 10)
                discount = product.price * 0.1
            elif product.product_code.startswith("DIS_15"):
                loyalty_points_earned += (product.price / 15)
                discount = product.price * 0.15
            else:
                loyalty_points_earned += (product.price / 5)
                discount = 0.00
            total_price += product.price - discount
        return Order(int(loyalty_points_earned), total_price)

    def __str__(self):
        product_list = "".join('%s'%product for product in self.products)
        return "Customer: %s \nBought: \n%s" % (self.customer, product_list)
```

Running the code:

```
def main():
    product1 = Product(10.0, "DIS_10_PRODUCT1", "product 1")
    product2 = Product(20.0, "DIS_10_PRODUCT2", "product 2")

    products = [product1, product2]

    customer = Customer("A Customer")

    shopping_cart = ShoppingCart(customer, products)

    product3 = Product(30.0, "DIS_10_PRODUCT3", "product 3")

    shopping_cart.add_product(product3)

    print(shopping_cart)

    order = shopping_cart.checkout()

    print(order)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

Based on the code above, I've decided to create three new classes: `DiscountHandler`, `LoyaltyPointsHandler` and `PriceCalculator`.

Here's my code (the models remain the same):

LoyaltyPointsHandler:

```
class LoyaltyPointsHandler:

    @staticmethod
    def calculate_loyalty_points_earned(product):
        if product.product_code.startswith("DIS_10"):
            return LoyaltyPointsHandler.earn_loyalty_points_with_DIS_10_code(product)

        elif product.product_code.startswith("DIS_15"):
            return LoyaltyPointsHandler.earn_loyalty_points_with_DIS_15_code(product)

        else:
            return LoyaltyPointsHandler.earn_loyalty_points_with_no_discount(product)

    @staticmethod
    def earn_loyalty_points_with_no_discount(product):
        loyalty_points_earned = product.price / 5
        return loyalty_points_earned

    @staticmethod
    def earn_loyalty_points_with_DIS_10_code(product):
        loyalty_points_earned = product.price / 10
        return loyalty_points_earned

    @staticmethod
    def earn_loyalty_points_with_DIS_15_code(product):
        loyalty_points_earned = product.price / 15
        return loyalty_points_earned
```

DiscountHandler:

```
class DiscountHandler(Discount):

    @staticmethod
    def calculate_discount(product):
        if product.product_code.startswith("DIS_10"):
            return DiscountHandler.calculate_10_per_cent_discount(product)

        elif product.product_code.startswith("DIS_15"):
            return DiscountHandler.calculate_15_per_cent_discount(product)

        else:
            return 0.00

    @staticmethod
    def calculate_10_per_cent_discount(product):
        discount = product.price * 0.1
        return discount

    @staticmethod
    def calculate_15_per_cent_discount(product):
        discount = product.price * 0.15
        return discount
```

PriceCalculator:

```
class PriceCalculator:

    @staticmethod
    def calculate_price_single_product_percentage_discount(product):
        final_price = product.price - DiscountHandler.calculate_discount(product)
        return final_price
```

ShoppingCart:

```
class ShoppingCart:
    def __init__(self, customer=Customer, products=[]):
        self.products = products
        self.customer = customer

    def add_product(self, product):
        self.products.append(product)

    def checkout(self):
        total_price = 0.00
        loyalty_points_earned = 0.00
        for product in self.products:
            loyalty_points_earned += LoyaltyPointsHandler.calculate_loyalty_points_earned(product)
            total_price += PriceCalculator.calculate_price_single_product_percentage_discount(product)
        return Order(int(loyalty_points_earned), total_price)

    def __str__(self):
        product_list = "".join('%s'%product for product in self.products)
        return "Customer: %s \nBought: \n%s" % (self.customer, product_list)
```

There was no time to show my full implementation to the person who was interviewing me and at the end of the interview I was asked what approach would I take if I had to implement a new type of discount, like the buy X and take Y home for example.

We talked a bit and I told them that maybe I'd create an interface called `Discount` with an abstract method `calculate_discount` and have the classes `DiscountPercentage` and `DiscountBuyXTakeY` implement it.

`Discount`would be like such:

```
class Discount (ABC):

    @staticmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def calculate_discount(product):
        pass
```

DiscountPercentage would be like such:

```
class DiscountPercentage(Discount):

    @staticmethod
    def calculate_discount(product):
        if product.product_code.startswith("DIS_10"):
            return DiscountPercentage.calculate_10_per_cent_discount(product)

        elif product.product_code.startswith("DIS_15"):
            return DiscountPercentage.calculate_15_per_cent_discount(product)

        else:
            return 0.00

    @staticmethod
    def calculate_10_per_cent_discount(product):
        discount = product.price * 0.1
        return discount

    @staticmethod
    def calculate_15_per_cent_discount(product):
        discount = product.price * 0.15
        return discount
```

But then how would I implement `DiscountBuyXTakeY`?

Because its `calculate_discount` method would need the number of products being purchased. But if I pass it as a parameter then the method signature would differ than that of the parent class and wouldn't it violate Liskov's Substitution principle then?

I also have the following questions:

- What could I have done better in the way of refactoring the code so it conforms to the SOLID principles? Was my approach good? Could I have gone further?
- And what about my approach at implementing this new discount type? Was I in the right track at the very least?
- Is it a bad practice to have so many static methods?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I would also suggest editing your post to include a complete list of business rules (involving prices/discounts/loyalty points/etc) or assumptions that the interviewers provided to you over the course of the interview. Otherwise, any potential reviewer here will have to extrapolate/guess at what those rules are based on the original pre-refactor code which could have a big influence on the suggested design.

Comment: I've edited the question to include business rules and the definition for `Discount` and `DiscountPercentage` classes. Please check whether this is better or if there's still any missing information. And thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Yes, there's a `main` function. I forgot to add it to the question, sorry. I've since edited my question to include it.

Comment: If not from the same interview, then at least very very similar to [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/277286/design-shopping-cart-system-interview-problem-python-3)

Answer (score 3):

I see no need for abstract classes here - there are no alternate implementations.

This string:

```
" Name: %s \n Price: %s \n" % (self.name, self.price)
```

has too much internal whitespace, and would be better as an interpolated f-string.

There is no need for the `Customer` class - that can just be a name string.

"Will receive %s" is a little confusing, and would be clearer as "Will receive %s points".

Your discount selection code is repeated and should be moved to a single place.

Add PEP484 type hints.

I see no need for the `Handler` and `Calculator` classes. The current application's business logic complexity level (not a lot) does not call for them. These can be demoted to functions or methods on other classes.

Consider using `locale.currency` for currency formatting.

You would benefit from making more of your classes immutable - `NamedTuple` is one easy way. The only class in your current implementation that needs to mutate is the `ShoppingCart`.

> Is it a bad practice to have so many static methods?

It's a smell, and in this case yes, it calls for refactoring and collapse of many of your classes down to simpler imperative code.

Don't use `[]` as an argument default - it's mutable, and since all defaults are referentially equal that has nasty consequences. One common way around this is to make an `Optional` that's filled in during the method.

### Suggested

One way of simplifying while retaining the same logic.

```py
from locale import currency, LC_ALL, setlocale
from typing import Optional, NamedTuple

setlocale(LC_ALL, '')


class Product(NamedTuple):
    price: float
    product_code: str
    name: str

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"Name: {self.name}\nPrice: {currency(self.price)}"


class Order(NamedTuple):
    points_earned: int
    total: float

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return (
            f"Total price: {currency(self.total)}"
            f"\nWill receive {self.points_earned} points"
        )


class Discount(NamedTuple):
    product: Product
    point_factor: float
    discount_factor: float

    @classmethod
    def for_product(cls, product: Product) -> 'Discount':
        for discount in (15, 10):
            if product.product_code.startswith(f"DIS_{discount}"):
                break
        else:
            discount = 5

        if discount > 5:
            points = 1/discount
        else:
            points = 0

        return cls(
            product=product,
            point_factor=points,
            discount_factor=1/discount,
        )

    @property
    def points(self) -> float:
        return self.product.price * self.point_factor

    @property
    def price(self) -> float:
        return self.product.price * (1 - self.discount_factor)


class ShoppingCart:
    def __init__(self, customer_name: str, products: Optional[list[Product]] = None) -> None:
        if products is None:
            products = []
        self.products = products
        self.customer_name = customer_name

    def add_product(self, product: Product) -> None:
        self.products.append(product)

    def checkout(self) -> Order:
        total_price = 0
        points = 0

        for product in self.products:
            discount = Discount.for_product(product)
            total_price += discount.price
            points += discount.points

        return Order(round(points), total_price)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        product_list = "\n".join(str(product) for product in self.products)
        return f"Customer: {self.customer_name}\nBought:\n{product_list}"


def main() -> None:
    products = [
        Product(10, "DIS_10_PRODUCT1", "product 1"),
        Product(20, "DIS_10_PRODUCT2", "product 2"),
    ]
    customer = "A Customer"
    shopping_cart = ShoppingCart(customer, products)

    product3 = Product(30, "DIS_10_PRODUCT3", "product 3")
    shopping_cart.add_product(product3)
    print(shopping_cart)

    order = shopping_cart.checkout()
    print(order)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### Output

```
Customer: A Customer
Bought:
Name: product 1
Price: $10.00
Name: product 2
Price: $20.00
Name: product 3
Price: $30.00
Total price: $54.00
Will receive 6 points
```